# Error when using a DDL for the <EditItemTemplate> of a LIstView control?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

In a VS2010/ASP.NET4 webpage, I have had a ListView control for editing and adding data.  Inside the , I added a DDL:

```
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server"         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7" DataTextField="Unit" DataValueField="UnitID"SelectedValue='<%# Bind("UnitID") %>' AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList></td>
```

While editing a data record, the DDL did show up for the Unit field.  I changed the Unit and clicked Update button, then an error popped up:
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UnitID', table 'Employee'.

What's wrong?

Update :

Reviewed the GridView and ListView codes and found something different between these two controls.

The GridView used TemplateField, instead of BoundField, for the DDL.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="UnitID" SortExpression="UnitID">  <EditItemTemplate><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource5"  DataTextField="Unit" DataValueField="UnitID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("UnitID") %>'> </asp:DropDownList></EditItemTemplate>;
```

and an ItemTemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UnitID") %>'></asp:Label></ItemTemplate> </asp:TemplateField>
```

I just added the DDL to the EditItemTemplate of the ListView:

```
<EditItemTemplate> <td><asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7"  DataTextField="Unit" DataValueField="UnitID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("UnitID") %>' AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList></td>
```

The ItemTemplate of the ListView showed:
   < ItenTemplate> ' />

Apparently, my ListView is missing some codes for the Text='<%# Bind("UnitID") %>.  Where should I add this ItemTemplate to the ListView?

Edit 2:

I manually added the  into the

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView2"

         runat="server"

         DataKeyNames="EmployeeID"

         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"

         InsertItemPosition="LastItem">

  <AlternatingItemTemplate>

             <tr style="">

                 <td>

                     <asp:Button ID="EditButton"

                         runat="server" CommandName="Edit"

                         Text="Edit" />

                 </td>

                 <td>

                     <asp:Label ID="EmployeeIDLabel"

                         runat="server"

                         Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>' />

                 </td>

                 <td>

                     <asp:Label ID="OOLIDLabel"

                         runat="server"

                         Text='<%# Eval("OOLID") %>' />

                 </td>

                 ....

             </tr>

</AlternatingItemTemplate>

<EditItemTemplate>

             <tr style="">

                 <td>

                     <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton"

                         runat="server" CommandName="Update"

                         Text="Update" />

                     <asp:Button ID="CancelButton"

                         runat="server" CommandName="Cancel"

                         Text="Cancel" />

                 </td>

                 <td>

                     <asp:Label ID="EmployeeIDLabel1"

                         runat="server"

                         Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>' />

                 </td>

                 <td>

                     <asp:TextBox ID="OOLIDTextBox"

                         runat="server"

                         Text='<%# Bind("OOLID") %>' />

                 </td>



                 <td>

          <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource7"

                 DataTextField="Unit" DataValueField="UnitID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("UnitID") %>' AutoPostBack="True">

                 </asp:DropDownList>

                 </td>

                 <!--<td>

                     <asp:TextBox ID="UnitIDTextBox"

                         runat="server"

                         Text='<%# Bind("UnitID") %>' />

                </td>-->



  </EditItemTemplate>

         <EmptyDataTemplate>

             <table runat="server" style="">

                 <tr>

                     <td>

                         No data was returned.</td>

                 </tr>

             </table>

         </EmptyDataTemplate>

         <InsertItemTemplate>

             <tr style="">



             </tr>

         </InsertItemTemplate>

         <ItemTemplate>

             <tr style="">

                 <td>

                     <asp:Button ID="EditButton"

                         runat="server" CommandName="Edit"

                         Text="Edit" />

                 </td>

                 <td>

                     <asp:Label ID="EmployeeIDLabel"

                         runat="server"

                         Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>' />

                 </td>

                 <td>

                     <asp:Label ID="OOLIDLabel"

                         runat="server"

                         Text='<%# Eval("OOLID") %>' />

                 </td>

                 ...

             </tr>

         </ItemTemplate>

         <LayoutTemplate>

             ...

         </LayoutTemplate>

         <SelectedItemTemplate>

             <tr style="">

                 <td>

                     <asp:Button ID="EditButton"

                         runat="server" CommandName="Edit"

                         Text="Edit" />

                 </td>

                 <td>

                     <asp:Label ID="EmployeeIDLabel"

                         runat="server"

                         Text='<%# Eval("EmployeeID") %>' />

                 </td>

                 <td>

                     <asp:Label ID="OOLIDLabel"

                         runat="server"

                         Text='<%# Eval("OOLID") %>' />

                 </td>

                 ...

         </SelectedItemTemplate>

     </asp:ListView>

     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3"

         runat="server"

         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EmployeeTestConnectionString %>"

         DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Employee] WHERE [EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID"

         InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Employee] ([OOLID], ) VALUES (@OOLID, @LASTNAME, "

         SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Employee] WHERE ([EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID)"

         UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Employee] SET [OOLID] = @OOLID, [.... WHERE [EmployeeID] = @EmployeeID">

         <DeleteParameters>

             <asp:Parameter Name="EmployeeID"

                 Type="Int32" />

         </DeleteParameters>

         <InsertParameters>

             <asp:Parameter Name="OOLID"

                 Type="Int32" />

             ....

         </InsertParameters>

         <SelectParameters>

             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1"

                 Name="EmployeeID"

                 PropertyName="SelectedValue"

                 Type="Int32" />

         </SelectParameters>

         <UpdateParameters>

             <asp:Parameter Name="OOLID"

                 Type="Int32" />

             <asp:Parameter Name="LASTNAME"

                 Type="String" />

             ....

         </UpdateParameters>

     </asp:SqlDataSource>

     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource7"

         runat="server"

         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:EmployeeTestConnectionString %>"

         SelectCommand="SELECT [UnitID], [Unit] FROM [Unit] order by [Unit] ASC">

     </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory. You are trying to update a value in a database field that does not accept empty values, but you are sending an empty one. The problem probably lies in the code that gets the value from the ListView and sends it to the database. Update your question with that code snippet.

Comment: @ VDWWD, I have updated my question can you please answer,

Comment: You need to post the snippet that sends the data to the database.

Comment: @ VDWWD,Can you plz check now